# Why is npm installing packages from private registry and not from registry.npmjs.org

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have create a `.nmprc` file in my project directory as:

```
@mycompany:registry=https://registry.mycompany.com/
```

However when I do `npm install` I see package dependencies which do not start with `@mycompany` also gets installed from `https://registry.mycompany.com/` and not from `https://registry.npmjs.org/`.

This is what I see in `package-lock.json`:

```
"yaml": {
  "version": "1.7.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.mycompany.com/yaml/-/yaml-1.7.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-qXROVp90sb83XtAoqE8bP9RwAkTTZbugRUTm5YeFCBfNRPEp2YzTeqWiz7m5OORHzEvrA/qcGS8hp/E+MMROYw==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.3"
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using an .npmrc File, the command `npm install` will try to find all packages in your companies registry `https://registry.mycompany.com/`

If you want to install all the other Packages you need to update your .npmrc File as followed.

Your Current .npmrc File:

`@mycompany:registry=https://registry.mycompany.com/`

Updated Version

`@mycompany:registry=https://registry.mycompany.com/`

`registry=https://registry.npmjs.org`

If you run `npm install` it will install all Packages with the `@mycompany` FLag from your companies Registry and it will try to install all other packages from the public npm Registry.

Comment: Is it possible this is only an issue for mac (and possibly linux) users?

Comment: this seems to be my experience as well, I had this issue only incur on M1 macs, on linux it works fine.